# What is this 'Unexpected token / in JSON at position 772' i am getting suddenly? (Angular2)

Tags: json, angular, components, generate, unexpected-token

Whenever I want to generate a new component or service, i suddenly get this error message: 'Unexpected token / in JSON at position 772'. I dont know how/what has caused this. There is also no reference to a specific file so I have no clue how to fix this.

Comment: Not enough details. Do you have any JSON files anywhere in your project? Do any of them have a '/' at pos 772? (perform some searches in your project first)

Comment: I would start looking at all your `*.json` files. Usual culprits like  `package.json`, `angular-cli.json`, etc...

Comment: @Grenther As im working on an Angular project I have a lot of json files.

Comment: @Narm is position a line or something different?

Comment: It turned out to be a commented line in angular.json .. at line 26. So that 'position 772' was a bit misleading for me. Thanks anyways

Comment: Please start New project. Because May be its occured not properly install. otherwise you have to check all .json file looks properly or not. Other one please check if any of the line has been commented out //like this check and remove.